# Record Sharing Using Role Hierarchies

Tags: role-hierarchy, owd, record-access-level, criteria-based-sharing

In OWD, for account access is "private". So,I have created sharing rule on Account object with the following criteria.

**Criteria** - Account Record Type= Account Type UK

**Share with-**   Role:"Marketing Manager UK"

I have created user with "Marketing Manager UK" role. when this user accessing contact record its showing 'insufficient access' error.(Owner records only possible to access)

If i have assigned other roles(which are above the "Marketing Manager UK" role) then this user is possible to access the contact record.

So,how can i access the contact record for the above user with "Marketing Manager UK" role.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the Contact OWD ? Is it controlled by parent ?

Comment: @Mihai- Yes, contact OWD is controlled by parent..

Answer (score 1):

You might have to check the profile of the user. It works well with a user having Standard Platform User profile. Also Default Account and Contract Access should be set to Read/Write.

Comment: Did this work for you?